# How do I make an iframe fill the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css

I've been coding a website in HTML, and I've been wanting to know how  to make an iframe fill the rest of my page without overlapping the navigation bar, and without making the whole page scroll.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! With this question, there's not much we can do to help you. Can you include some code you've tried? That way, we can figure out what the root of your problem is. Thanks!

Comment: For future posts, please show us your code using jsfiddle tool http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give us a code as example it will be very difficult to give you a precise answer.

What I understood is that you want a tag to fill the rest of the page. I assume you're talking about the height.

You can use css to get that:

```
html, body, iframe {height: 100%}
```

If you have a navigation over the iframe, you'll need to reduce iframe's height minus navigation height

For that you can use a calc:

```
iframe {height: calc(100% - 80px)}
```

Example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15qzj9oh/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this, with jQuery:

```
   $(window).resize(function () {
    var iframeHeight = $(window).height() - ($('#navigationbar').innerHeight())
    $('#iframe').innerHeight(alturaContenedores);    

});
```