# Chrome replaces main window when loading iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I wrote a simple viewer for Greek syntax trees:

http://ibiblio.org/bgreek/resources/syntax-trees/reader/

On Chrome, when I am not running this locally, the main window is replaced when the iframe is loaded.  See below. How can I fix this so that the main window remains on all browsers?

The main page has an iframe into which I load an XML file that is formatted with its own CSS stylesheet:

```
<iframe id="display" src=""></iframe>
```

The code loads the file into this iframe when the button is clicked:

```
function loadPassage() {
    var passage = document.getElementById("passage").value;

    document.getElementById("display").src = treeFile(passage, "nestle1904");
}
```

The body hides the scrollbar, the iframe does not:

```
body {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100em;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue comes from hiding the overflow on the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I learned:  when the iframe is loaded, some browsers scroll past the area of the parent window to make room for the iframe, some do not.  If I enable the scrollbar in the parent window, it is easy to see this happening.  If I disable it, it looks like the parent window disappears, but it is merely scrolling past the top part of the window without providing a way to scroll back to it.

I can get rid of this problem by reducing the size of the iframe.  That gives me a simpler problem to solve:  how can I create the child window to take up all the remaining space beneath it in a device independent manner.

And someone provided a nice answer here:

[How do I make an iframe fill the rest of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626870/how-do-i-make-an-iframe-fill-the-rest-of-the-page)

So it works now, using this CSS:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

html, body, iframe {height: 100%}

#top {
    height: 120px;
}

form {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}

form input {
    background-color: white;
}

iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute `overflow: hidden` from the element `body` and add `overflow: hidden` to the element `html`

```
html {overflow: hidden}
body {background-color: antiquewhite; margin: 8px;}
```

so you will have no scrollbar in your browser, but there will be in `iFrame`.

Comment: I tried moving `overflow:hidden`, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.  This change is now at the same location as the original.

Here is the current css:

    body {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    iframe {
        overflow: scroll;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100em;
    }

Comment: Hmmm ... if I don't disable the main scrollbar, it loads the page and scrolls past the top area of the page.  So it doesn't look like the entire window is being replaced, it just scrolls past it, and since the scrollbar is disabled there is now way to come back to it.

So what I really need is a way to make sure the top area cannot be scrolled past ...

Comment: As I sad, html overflow is the problem.